# Mysql - Join query

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 queries:-

Query 1:-

```
mysql> select mccid_c, id_c from contacts_cstm where accountnumber_c = '1601480000552527';
250762  | 475093000013882513
```

Query 2:-

```
mysql> select first_name, last_name from contacts where id = '475093000013882513';
John        | Doe
```

id in contacts = id_c in contacts_cstm

I required a join query to get mccid_c, first_name, last_name in one query

Thanks!

Comment: so what are you waiting for?

Comment: So try: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic usecase of the `join` syntax:

```
SELECT mccid_c, first_name, last_name
FROM   contacts_cstm cc
JOIN   contacts c ON c.id  = cc.id_c
WHERE  c.id = '475093000013882513'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select a.mccid_c, b.first_name, b.last_name from contacts_cstm a inner join contacts b where a.id_c=b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple tables in your single SQL query. The act of joining in MySQL refers to smashing two or more tables into a single table.

You can use JOINS in SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to join MySQL tables.But firstly you need a **common column** (attribut),suppose it is '**tutorial_author**' between the two tables that you want to join it.

```
SELECT a.mccid_c,  b.first_name , b.last_name
        FROM contacts_cstm a, contacts b
        WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author and a.accountnumber_c = '1601480000552527' and b.id = '475093000013882513';
```

I hope it will help you, best regards